# How to get the coordinates of drawn map elements in Python matplotlib Basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to retrieve the points Basemap uses to draw the Great Salt Lake
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have created a map element, i.e. m = Basemap(), get the vertices like this...

```
m.drawcoastlines().properties()['paths'][0].vertices # Lake outline
m.drawcoastlines().properties()['paths'][1].vertices # Island outline
```

Which returns arrays of latitude/longitude pair for each point used to draw the outline.

```
array([[-112.766113281, 41.660003662],
       [-112.782218933, 41.643051147],
       [-112.786392212, 41.619445801],
       ....and so on]])
```

I imagine you can do the same for drawn states, counties, etc.